# "195 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" in Xcode when having cordova-plugin-firebase and then adding cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks

Tags: xcode, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a Cordova project working with cordova-plugin-firebase. I need to add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks, but when I do it doesn't build any more and throws the following message:

> "195 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64".

[image: image of the error]

I assume that they collide in some way and import something twice, since it was building properly before adding the second plugin, and works well again if I remove it. I have seen that it probably has to do with -ObjC (since I see it in the error msg and I have seen related stuff when researching around). I'm not very sure where to look.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: I never did, in fact. I ended up using a different plugin (and a different platform from firebase) for the dynamic links.
Its https://branch.io/ / https://www.npmjs.com/package/branch-cordova-sdk if you want to try it